# Running an executable with input using makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I.
tiling_file=blocking.cpp
sequential_file=sequential.cpp
n1 = 100
n2=7 
n3=4

all: tiling sequential run
tiling:
    $(CC) $(tiling_file) -fopenmp -o block

sequential: 
    $(CC) $(sequential_file) -fopenmp -o seq

run:
    ./block $(n1) $(n2) $(n3)
```

the block executable takes in three inputs(as specified by n1,n2,n3) .However when I execute make I get the following ouput

```
g++ blocking.cpp -fopenmp -o block
g++ sequential.cpp -fopenmp -o seq
./block 100 7 4
```

The executable doesn't take the input unless I type 100 7 4 again and press enter.
How can I run it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The executable doesn't take the input unless I type 100 7 4 again and press enter. How can I run it?

That executable probably expects data in its standard input rather than command line arguments:

```
run:
    echo "$(n1) $(n2) $(n3)" | ./block
```

---

I would normally have the following rule for running executables:

```
run_% : %
    echo "${$*.stdin}" | ./$< ${$*.args}
.PHONY: run_%
```

And then I would define an executable:

```
mytest : # something that builds mytest executable
mytest.stdin := "this goes into the standard input of mytest"
mytest.args := --verbose --dry-run
```

And invoke make like this:

```
make run_mytest
```

---

Another point is that your recipes must produce the file they promise to produce. Presently, it promises to build a file named `tiling`, but builds one named `block` instead.

Fixes:

```
tiling:
    $(CC) $(tiling_file) -fopenmp -o $@

sequential: 
    $(CC) $(sequential_file) -fopenmp -o $@
```

In the above `$@` stands for target name, `tiling` and `sequential` correspondingly.

Comment: This may be just my opinion, but I'm not keen on makefiles that run their targets.   The job of make is to build the target.   If you want to build and run in one step, you can create a bash script that does  `make target && ./target p1 p2`, etc.

Comment: It's basically semantics -- the purpose of make is to build something, and the purpose of scripts is to run things. One caveat of running from make that I can think of off the top of my head is that the environment in make may have some unexpected settings (different shell than you're expecting, different path etc).  That could lead to different behaviors when running from the command line vs make.

Comment: @John All these caveats apply to shell scripts equally as well, don't they?